# Another Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle

My prefix is a scam.

My infix is a vessel.

My suffix is a number.

What word am I?

Hint #1:

> This word can be an adjective, noun, and a verb.

Hint #2:

> Think of the number more loosely.

Comment: Good idea, will do. edit: done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The word is:

> **CONJUGATE**

*My prefix is a scam.*

> A **CON** is a scam.

*My infix is a vessel.*

> A **JUG** is a vessel for holding liquids.

*My suffix is a number.*

> **ATE** is a homophone for '8' (eight), satisfying Hint 2 ('Think of the number more loosely'...)

Re Hint 1:

> '[**CONJUGATE**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conjugate)' can be an adjective (e.g. 'conjugate words' = '*having the same derivation and therefore usually some likeness in meaning*'), a noun (in a [mathematical sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_(square_roots))), or a verb ('to conjugate' = 'to join together').

Comment: That was fast...

Comment: @MakeHellTal fast can be an adjective, noun, or verb ;)